# How to match and extract section number and title in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match and extract the section and subsection numbers and titles in any of the following formats:

```
section
1 section
2. section
2.1 subsection
2.1.1 subsection
2.1.1. subsection
2.1.1. subsection multiple words less than 40 chars
```

I tried

```
^(\d{1,3}?(\.?\d{1,3}?\.?)*)?\s*(\w*)$
```

It doesn't match the second one. I also prefer to have two desired groups (the section number and section title)

Comment: You are expecting it to match 1-3 digits, where 2. is followed by 0 digits, so I think `\d{0,3}` would work. Note that currently as all the quantifiers are optional, it would also match an empty string, using `\w+` would prevent that. Or like `^(?:\d{1,3}\.?(?:\d{1,3}\.?)* )?[^\W\d]+` https://regex101.com/r/oJ6R2D/1

Comment: With 2 groups `^(?:(\d{1,3}\.?(?:\d{1,3}\.?)*)?) ?([^\W\d]+)` https://regex101.com/r/oxY99s/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird how could I modify your sugestion if the section title could be one or more words (alphnumeric) and the total length between 5 and 40. I tried `^(?:(\d{1,3}\.?(?:\d{1,3}\.?)*)?) ?([^\W\s\d]{5,40})$` but didn't match "1 section section"

Comment: If you don't want to match spaces only `^(?:(\d{1,3}\.?(?:\d{1,3}\.?)*)?) ?(\w[\w \t]{4,39})` https://regex101.com/r/Oa5AI5/1 or use `[\w\s]{4,39}` but `\s` could also match a newline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use

```
^(\d{1,3}\.?(?:\d{1,3}\.?)*)? ?([^\W\d]+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d{1,3}\.?(?:\d{1,3}\.?)*` Match 1-3 digits optionally followed by parts with a `.` and 1-3 digits
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `?` Match optional space
- `([^\W\d]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times a word char without digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JC0lv9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3orAYa)

```
import re

regex = r"^(\d{1,3}\.?(?:\d{1,3}\.?)*)? ?([^\W\d]+)"

s = ("section\n"
    "1 section\n"
    "2. section\n"
    "2.1 subsection\n"
    "2.1.1 subsection\n"
    "2.1.1. subsection")

print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
[
    ('', 'section'),
    ('1', 'section'),
    ('2.', 'section'),
    ('2.1', 'subsection'),
    ('2.1.1', 'subsection'),
    ('2.1.1.', 'subsection')
]
```

If you want to match 5-40 chars in group 2 including digits, you can start the match with a word character to match at least a single word character, and repeat for example the allowed characters 4-39 times in a character class.

```
^(\d{1,3}\.?(?:\d{1,3}\.?)*)? ?(\w[\w \t]{4,39})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HNHL7m/1)

Answer (score 0):

The first one might be a special case, but generally .split()  gives you exactly what you want:

```
toc = '''\
section
1 section
2. section
2.1 subsection
2.1.1 subsection
2.1.1. subsection
2.1.1. subsection multiple words less than 40 chars'''

for line in toc.split('\n'):
    l = line.split(' ', 1)
    print(l)
```

Output is:

```
['section']
['1', 'section']
['2.', 'section']
['2.1', 'subsection']
['2.1.1', 'subsection']
['2.1.1.', 'subsection']
['2.1.1.', 'subsection multiple words less than 40 chars']
```